# How await keyword works?

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, async-await, coroutine

For a given below co-routine(`f`),

```
import csv
import urllib

def f(resp):
   print('Line 1')
   yield csv.reader(resp.read().decode('utf-8'))


def h():
    url = 'http://www.nasdaq.com/screening/companies-by-industry.aspx?exchange=NYSE&render=download'    
    resp = urllib.urlopen(url)
    cr = f(resp)
```

`cr = f(resp)` assigns an iterator object to `cr`,

`cr.next()` execute Line 1 and block at yield keyword.

My understanding is, with syntax `cr=f(resp)` there is no event-loop(task scheduler) with threading, behind the scene

---

Instead of saying `cr=f(resp)`(above), If the same function(`h`) has `await f(resp)` as mentioned below(`await` keyword asks for `async` syntax),

```
async def h_async():
    url = 'http://www.nasdaq.com/screening/companies-by-industry.aspx?exchange=NYSE&render=download'    
    resp = urllib.urlopen(url)
    await f(resp)
```

then,

How `await f(resp)` different from `cr=f(resp)`?

How `h_async()` different from `h()`? Does `await` keyword introduce event-loop(task scheduler) with threading, behind the scene, as shown in this sample [code](https://github.com/shamhub/Design_pattern/tree/master/EventHandling-Observer_pattern)

Comment: A long read can be found here: https://snarky.ca/how-the-heck-does-async-await-work-in-python-3-5/

Comment: @Caramiriel  I read this before raising this question. But the author mix up asyncio package with it.

Comment: `await` works for any co-routine/task/future, so in terms of a co-routine it isn't that much different (an async method is effectively a co-routine, see: https://repl.it/repls/OrchidWarmheartedLinks). The power of async/await comes into play with tasks, where methods can be scheduled in a background thread and thus be run concurrently. Imagine initiating a download, doing some calculations in the meantime, and `await`ing the data when you actually need it. I'll leave a full answer to someone that can explain it better, as this material is fairly new to me as well.

Answer (score 1):

`await EXPR` means event tasks scheduler can switch on something other at this step (for example, pull something that's ready from the task queue), and also indicates that `EXPR` is awaitable. If `EXPR` is a coroutine, it means it can have subsequent `await`s inside, and again something else can be also executed when this coroutine is in non-blocking waiting state (like IO or network response, sleep, etc)

Comment: With syntax `cr = f(resp)`, Does event task scheduler work behind the scene?